# PHP get array from regex

Tags: php, regex

I've got string like

```
$content = "Some content some content
[images ids="10,11,20,30,40"]
Some content";
```

I want to remove `[images ids="10,11,20,30,40"]` part from it and get ids part as php `array(10,11,20,30,40)`

Is it possible with regex?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Code please.

Comment: I've made string replace and then array explode by comma, but I dont think it is good solution.

Comment: @Kluska000 if you know the format of your string, then what you're doing sounds like a good idea to me

Comment: Yeah, that's what anyone is going to do...

Comment: You probably can't do both those things with a single preg function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$txt = <<<LOD
Some content some content
[images ids="10,11,20,30,40"]
Some content
LOD;

$result = array();

$txt = preg_replace_callback('~(?:\[images ids="|\G(?!^))([0-9]+)(?:,|"])~',
    function ($m) use (&$result) { $result[] = $m[1]; }, $txt);
        
echo $txt . '<br>' . print_r($result, true);
```

The `\G` anchor can be very useful in this situation since it's a kind of anchor that means *"at the start of the string or contiguous to a precedent match"*.

However, nothing in the pattern checks if there is a last number followed by `"]`. If you need to do that, you must add a lookahead to the pattern:

```
~(?:\[images ids="|\G(?!^))([0-9]+)(?=(?:,[0-9]+)*"])(?:,|"])~
```

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks anubhava! The `\G` feature is like a philosopher's stone, you search it for a long time, but it's very powerful.

Comment: Yes I learnt about `\G` in one of your previous answers sometime back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's the structure of content and it doesn't get any more complex, then:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

More would need to be added to narrow it down if it is more complex.